# Get absolute url to image with jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm working on a web-scraper for a website but my current code only scrapes relative urls to images. How can I convert those urls to absolute ones?

Second problem: when I combine the link manually `http://www.arena-offshore.com/iframe/list/../../res2.php?res=site/big/08032016130016552-GEMI-gözcü1.jpg&g=500&u=335` and open the link in a browser, I only see some sort of text file instead of the picture. Is it possible to get a direct link to the picture, that is displayed normally in a browser?

Current code:

```
Document doc;
String url = "http://www.arena-offshore.com/iframe/list/list-detail.php?category=1&page=&id=956&id=956";
try {
doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36")
.get();
Elements elements = doc.select("#u702_img");

for (Element element : elements) {
String src = element.attr("src");
System.out.println(src);
}
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output

```
../../res2.php?res=site/big/08032016130016552-GEMI-gözcü1.jpg&g=500&u=335
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text file *is* the image. You can see that it is a `jpg` because the file starts with:

> ÿØÿàJFIFÿþ>CREATOR: gd-**jpeg** v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62)

When you save the text file in your browser (Right click > Save as...) and give the file the .jpg extension it will be rendered correctly.

You can take the image URL from your `src` output:

```
String baseUrl = "http://www.arena-offshore.com/";
String output = "../../res2.php?res=site/big/08032016130016552-GEMI-gözcü1.jpg&g=500&u=335";
int start = output.indexOf("=") + 1;
int end   = output.indexOf("&", start);
String imageUrl = baseUrl + output.substring(start, end); 
// Gives:
// http://www.arena-offshore.com/site/big/08032016130016552-GEMI-g%C3%B6zc%C3%BC1.jpg
```

Then you could download the image using jsoup:

```
byte[] bytes = Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreContentType(true).execute().bodyAsBytes();
```

Note that there is also the `element.absUrl("src");` method in Jsoup to get the absolute URL of an image, although that may not work in your case since it points to a php page.

Answer (score 1):

From your current output, just remove `res2.php?res=` and ending parameters `&g=500&u=335`:

You will get the direct link

```
http://www.arena-offshore.com/site/big/08032016130016552-GEMI-g%C3%B6zc%C3%BC1.jpg
```

Comment: First he should get the absolute url though: 
`String src = element.attr("abs:src");
src.substring(0, src.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf("&g")).replace("res2.php?res=", "");`